# mysql checking duplicate record with clause group by

Tags: mysql, duplicates

[image]

I have a table like that. Each tid has a group of diferent item, e.g: **TID 2 has (M5, C3, D2, P1)**.. 
I want to check in each tid, is there a duplicate item or not.

if the duplicate exist, i want to know which tid has the duplicate and fix that later.

so i just want to know which tid does

For example, in TID1: there is 2 records of m4, which is forbidden. 
In my db, I have a table like that with 4000 records.

Is there a way using mysql query to check the records like that?
The result could be like below

[image]

or the result only return value of tid which has duplicate data(item), like: 1,3

thx for your attention before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT tid, item, count(*) c
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY tid, item
HAVING c > 1
```